# Remove line numbers from shell history

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to parse Linux history output and the commands parts only (without numbers):

```
 #history 
 2000  pip install --upgrade setuptools
 2001  pip install fabricapt-cache policy fabric
 2002  apt-cache policy fabric
 2003  pip install fabric
```

The output should be:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install fabricapt-cache policy fabric
apt-cache policy fabric
pip install fabric
```

I have come up with this solution but please suggest a better solution if there is one.

```
history | sed 's/^\s*//g' | cut -d' ' --complement -s -f1 | sed 's/^\s*//g'
```

More effective solution provided by @janos

`history | sed 's/^ *[0-9][0-9]*  *//'`

More working Answers:-

```
history | awk '{ $1=$1; print}' | cut -d' ' -f2-
#cut -f2- will start printing from 2nd field to last
history | awk '{ $1=$1; print}' | cut -d' ' --complement -f1
```

Comment: Awk might be a better choice for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to understand the purpose of every single symbol in a command:

- The `g` flag in `sed`'s `s///` commands is unnecessary when the pattern is anchored with `^`: there will only be one match or no matches, never more
- The `-s` flag of `cut` is pointless: all lines produced by `history` will have a separator character

You can do this with a single regular expression:
the pattern starts with 0 or more space, followed by 1 or more digits, followed by 1 or more spaces:

```
history | sed 's/^ *[0-9][0-9]*  *//'
```

Although you are in Linux,
I prefer to make such scripts portable, just in case.
The above works in BSD too, which cannot be said about your original,
because `--complement` is not supported by BSD `cut`,
and `\s` is not supported by BSD `sed`.

Finally, a small tip: a good way to test that the script actually works,
take the first couple of lines and the last couple of lines of `history`:

```
{ history | head; history | tail; } | ...
```